# why does jquery ajax go to the url rather than load it?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What the heck is up with this code?

```
    $(".submit").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    var name = $(".name").val();
    var email = $(".email").val();
    var comment = $(".comment").val();
    var articleId = $(".articleId").val(); 
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment+ '&articleId=' + articleId;
    if(name=='' || comment==''){
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    }
    else{
        alert('so far so good');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../_includes/process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                alert("succes");
                $(".updating").fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Everything works until `$.ajax` finds process.php and instead of reading and executing the code it actually goes to that page in the browser.  I tried using `return false` after the ajax call but then the code in process.php never happens.

here is process.php

```
    <?php 
    // code to establish connection first

    if($_POST){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    $comment=$_POST['comment'];
    $comment=mysql_real_escape_string($comment);

    $articleId=$_POST['articleId']; 
    $articleId=mysql_real_escape_string($articleId);

    if(!empty($email)){
            $lowercase = strtolower($email);
    }

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(name,email,comment,articleId) VALUES ('$name','$email','$comment','$articleId')");

    if($result){
            echo "success";
    } else {
            echo "there were erros" . mysql_error();
    }
    exit;

    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you have `return false;` in the right place? i.e inside the last set of brackets.

Comment: I put it right after the else ending bracket.. where should it be?

Comment: that should be fine then. What happens when you have the `return false`, does firebug or chrome developer tools give any errors that may be happening in process.php?

Comment: process.php works when it gets loaded (switches url of browser) but I'm also not getting my success alert

Comment: Just to be sure, try using an absolute url for process.php. e.g. `http://domain.com/process.php` and make sure you are accessing the variables correctly in the script and echoing out. You should be able to see the response from process.php in whatever dev tools you are using.

Comment: I just added my php code to see if that might have a problem. Your right I'm not getting a response in firebug, it shows the post variables but no response... thats because I'm not actually echoing anything yet?

Comment: yes, that's right, you need to echo something out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prevent the default action of your submit button:

```
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked");
    ...
});
```

Comment: hmm I added this in but I'm having the same problem I had with `return false` process.php won't do its stuff

Comment: it should work - check your paths, check if you're using POST vars in your php file.. and just for the sake of test try to comment everything out and echo a string to see if it's working and sends back a reply to your Ajax call

Comment: perhaps my php is the problem, I will edit my question to add in that code.

Comment: try to echo a single success message after your query and see in Firebug if it comes back. Also echo an error message in case of error.

Comment: your `$result` variable is nowhere set

Comment: comment everything out and live just 1 echo on the page to see if the request gets through and you actually connecting to that file

Comment: alright, the request isn't getting through.  I put `echo "anything at all";` and it did not have a response in firebug. So how do I connect to the file correctly?

Comment: it depends on your folder structure

Comment: my javascript file is in a folder _scripts/ my php file is in a folder _includes/ both of those folders are in the root directory. I used an absolute link http://mydomain.com/_includes/process.php but that gives no response either.

Comment: no errors thrown or anything. But, I added an `errors: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert('errors');}` to the `$.ajax` function and now I get that alert every time. So, something is continually failing. Perhaps the `<form action''>` has to be set to something in my html?

Comment: it doesn't matter - if it's not set it falls back to current page

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer and re-ask this question in an attempt to make it more relevant to my problem, because technically you did answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo something out from process.php if you want to know it worked ok.

e.g

```
echo 'success';
exit; // just incase
```

then in your ajax request

```
success: function(response){
            if (response == 'success') {
                alert("success");
                $(".updating").fadeIn(400);
            }
            else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
```

even if you aren't echoing out, process.php should still work.

try turning on error reporting if it still isn't working:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: I have error reporting on, I went straight to process.php in my browser to see if it showed any errors and it did not.  Firebug says there is no response still.  I don't really know what else to try.